# Javascript button with image / css?

Tags: javascript, button

I've go a somewhat silly question...
Cant figure out how to create a button with image 
So far I've come to the the

```
<form>
    <input type="button" value="back" onclick="history.back()">
</form>
```

Instead of "back" button I would like to have f.e images/back.jpg button

Do i need to create a new class button in css?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `<button>` tag and image as html content.

```html
<button type="submit" name="someName" value="someValue" onclick="history.back()">
  <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/IX7ZV.png" alt="SomeAlternateText">
</button>
```

Comment: Thank you, is there a possibilty to remove that button frame around the original button picture?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a background url style on the button.

```
<button class="button"></button><br>
<input class="button" type="button" onclick="history.back()">
<style>
.button {
  height:50px;
  width:50px;
  background: url(https://lh3.ggpht.com/sqPcTNRtM6vc4pzWXWXIR6KxnRwbIz4LIYKvqwr1l__gPYkx24sV4Ak1oc2sN99dVA=w300);
  background-size: 100% 100%;
}
</style>
```

See [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lzooce0y/)